# How to get past black screen with mouse icon while installing on Gateway MX6920?

Tags: boot, system-installation, laptop, live-cd

I have an old Gateway MX6920 laptop that got a virus on its hard drive so I put in a new one from another laptop. When i turn it on it tries to load Windows but fails so I'm going to try to put Ubuntu on it (because I heard it's a good OS).

I downloaded the 32-bit desktop version of Ubuntu and burned it to a CD. I put the CD in the computer, went to the boot menu, and selected CD-ROM. The computer tries to boot but stops at a black screen with a mouse icon sitting in the middle of the display.

I have no idea what's going on, so please help.

Comment: i have tried it in nomodeset still nothing i checked disc and found one error im attempting to do MD5 test if anyone has an easy detailed walk through on how to do it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

1. [MD5 test the `.iso` image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) you downloaded and used to make the CD.

   If that doesn't check out, you'll have to re-download the Ubuntu `.iso` and start over with a new CD.
2. [Check the CD for defects](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html), as it may itself be corrupted, physically damaged, or otherwise not properly accessible, even if the image isn't. You should do this on the machine you're trying to install Ubuntu on, as this will also ensure that your CD drive is working.

   If this reveals errors, fails, or cannot be selected, write a new CD. If it fails for that, too, make sure you're following [a correct procedure](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows) for burning the CD, and try burning it as slowly as possible (which can sometimes avoid problems).
3. Try booting with the [`nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) boot option.

If none of this helps, you should then **edit your question** to include information about exactly what you did and what happened. Then other suggestions or solutions can be proposed.

Comment: thanks for the answer i tried instaling with nomodeset and i tried launching ubuntu whithout instaling with and without nomodeset still nothing but i did do a disc check and it found 1 error in a file so does that mean i should re download ubuntu or do the md5 test or both

Comment: @tomkruse If you checked the disc for defects as detailed in step 2 and found an error, but you didn't MD5 test the `.iso` image, you should now MD5 test the `.iso` image. If it comes out correct, you know that your `.iso` file is fine, but that it's just a bad burn. If the MD5 test reveals that the `.iso` is corrupted, then you need to redownload the `.iso` file.

Comment: okay i attempted to do the MD5 test but i have no clue how to do it so can you please give some what of an easy walk through of how to do it im not that much of a technical guy but i can understand most stuff

Comment: @tomkruse [This part](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows) of the page linked to in the question describes how to do the MD5 test on Windows. Assuming you're using this method and having trouble with it, can you provide more information about what you need to know, or what's not working right?

Comment: okay i think i did this right and when i hit compare it said MD5 check sums are differnt

Comment: @tomkruse Since the MD5 sum is wrong, you need to redownload the Ubuntu installation `.iso` file. Then MD5 test the new one to make sure it's right, and continue from there.

Comment: ok thank you for all your help ill download it tomorrow and do the test then hopefully it work

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Gateway MX6920 last night! Glad there are a few of us left out there keepin' it real (like back in 2005, yo). Since I didn't trust the burner not to make mistakes after all these years of abuse, I ran it on the second-to-lowest speed setting to make sure there were no errors. I think it was 2x speed burning using "Free ISO Burner". It booted and installed nicely. Now I'm learning how to get around in this new world. It's great!